# Bulk Upsert using '$addToSet' to add a set of objects creates NESTED arrays of dictionaries instead of array of dictionaries

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to bulk upsert data to mongoDB using PyMongo

My objective is as follows:

1. Check if working_appl_id exists in the database.
2. If it exists, concatenate the unique objects in the 'toBeAdded' array with the corresponding fields in mongoDB.
3. If it does not exist, then create a record with "appl_id" as 'working_appl_id' and set the 'toBeAdded' dictionary as well.

E.g.
Inserting the following into an empty database

```
    Appl Id | First Name | Last Name | Ip Address | Ip Country  
    123 | John | Johnson | x.x.x.x | USA
    123 | Peter | Peterson | y.y.y.y | FRA
```

should result in

```
{
    'appl_id': 123,
    'name':[
        {'first':'John', 'last':'Johnson'}, 
        {'first':'Peter', 'last':'Peterson'}
    ],
    'ip':[
        {'address': 'x.x.x.x', 'country': 'USA'},
        {'address': 'y.y.y.y', 'country': 'FRA'}
    ]
},
```

Now adding the following to the above database

```
    Appl Id | First Name | Last Name | Ip Address | Ip Country  
    123 | Mayer | Mayerson | x.x.x.x | USA
    123 | John | Johnson | z.z.z.z | GER
    456 | Will | Willson | x.x.x.x | USA
```

should result in

```
{
    'appl_id': 123,
    'name':[
        {'first':'John', 'last':'Johnson'}, 
        {'first':'Peter', 'last':'Peterson'}, 
        {'first':'Mayer', 'last':'Mayerson'}
    ],
    'ip':[
        {'address': 'x.x.x.x', 'country': 'USA'},
        {'address': 'y.y.y.y', 'country': 'FRA'},
        {'address': 'z.z.z.z', 'country': 'GER'}
    ]
},
{
    'appl_id': 456,
    'name': [
        {'first':'Will', 'last':'Willson'},
    ],
    'ip': [
        {'address': 'x.x.x.x', 'country': 'USA'}
    ]
},
```

My Code looks like this

```
db = client['some_db']
col = db['some_collection']
bulk = col.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()

working_appl_id=123
toBeAdded={
    "name":[
        {'first':'John', 'last':'Johnson'}, 
        {'first':'Peter', 'last':'Peterson'}
    ]
    "ip":[
        {'address': 'x.x.x.x', 'country': 'USA'},
        {'address': 'y.y.y.y', 'country': 'FRA'}
    ]
}

bulk.find({"appl_id": working_appl_id}).upsert() \
    .update(
        {
            '$addToSet': toBeAdded,
            '$setOnInsert': {
                "appl_id": working_appl_id,
             },
        }
    )

res = bulk.execute()
```

The output of my code is not the desired output. The output of my code is as such

```
{
    'appl_id': 123,
    'name': [
        [
            {'first':'John', 'last':'Johnson'}, 
            {'first':'Peter', 'last':'Peterson'}
        ],
        [
            {'first':'Mayer', 'last':'Mayerson'}
            {'first':'John', 'last':'Johnson'}, 
        ],
      ],
      'ip': [
          [
              {'address': 'x.x.x.x', 'country': 'USA'},
              {'address': 'y.y.y.y', 'country': 'FRA'}
          ],
          [
              {'address': 'x.x.x.x', 'country': 'USA'},
              {'address': 'z.z.z.z', 'country': 'GER'}
          ]
      ]
},
{
    'appl_id': 456,
    'name': [
        {'first':'Will', 'last':'Willson'},
    ]
    'ip': [
        {'address': 'x.x.x.x', 'country': 'USA'}
    ]
},
```

**Instead of having 1 array with unique dictionaries, I get an array of array with dictionaries. (See keys 'name' or 'ip')**

**How do I remove the perform the upsert without creating an array of arrays?**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @D.SM Sorry, I am not used to posting here. Thank you for your feedback. I have made updates to the post. I added the output of my code and and also the problem question. Is this better?

Comment: I think what you need is described in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#value-to-add-is-an-array , i.e. using $each.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#addtoset-modifiers

Comment: @D.SM Thank you for your help. The documentation really helped and I could not find it before  despite trying to search extensively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toBeAdded` variable consists of an array of objects you want to insert and when you try to insert an array by `$addToSet` or `$push` update methods, it will insert the entire array itself instead of the objects inside that array.

You have to loop through the objects inside the array and insert each element by individually update commands. or you can use the `$each` operator to let MongoDB do that work for you.

Here is how your code should be:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient


client = MongoClient()

db = client['temp']
col = db['answer_temp']
bulk = col.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()

working_appl_id=123
toBeAdded={
    "name":[
        {'first':'John', 'last':'Johnson'},
        {'first':'Peter', 'last':'Peterson'}
    ],
    "ip":[
        {'address': 'x.x.x.x', 'country': 'USA'},
        {'address': 'y.y.y.y', 'country': 'FRA'}
    ]
}

bulk.find({"appl_id": working_appl_id}).upsert() \
    .update(
    {
        '$addToSet': {
            "name": { "$each": toBeAdded["name"] },
            "ip": { "$each": toBeAdded["ip"] }
        },
        '$setOnInsert': {
            "appl_id": working_appl_id,
        },
    }
    )

res = bulk.execute()
```

> **Note:** I haven't tested my code in my local, so do let me know in case of issues

Also, `initialize_unordered_bulk_op` is deprecated. You can re-write it to something like this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.errors import BulkWriteError
from pymongo import UpdateOne


client = MongoClient()

db = client['temp']
col = db['answer_temp']
# bulk = col.bulk_write()

working_appl_id=123
toBeAdded={
    "name":[
        {'first':'John', 'last':'Johnson'},
        {'first':'Peter', 'last':'Peterson'}
    ],
    "ip":[
        {'address': 'x.x.x.x', 'country': 'USA'},
        {'address': 'y.y.y.y', 'country': 'FRA'}
    ]
}

requests = []
requests.append(
    UpdateOne(
        filter={
            "appl_id": working_appl_id
        },
        update={
            '$addToSet': {
                "name": { "$each": toBeAdded["name"] },
                "ip": { "$each": toBeAdded["ip"] }
            },
            '$setOnInsert': {
                "appl_id": working_appl_id,
            },
        },
        upsert=True
    )
)

try:
    col.bulk_write(requests, ordered=False)
except BulkWriteError as bwe:
    print(bwe.details)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The changes you made worked perfectly. I appreciate all your help. :)